# |_ in django template tag

Tags: python, django, web, django-templates

I work as content manager and have access to CMS of a website. It is built with Django. 
In some templates objects are taken as `{{object_name.object_atribute|_}}`. I cannot understand what `|_` do

Comment: You need to search for declaration of `_`, in django it's usually translation function.

Comment: Could it be a [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-template-tags/)?

Answer (score 0):

In django template filters spesified with " | " like;`{{object_name.object_atribute|default_if_none:"nothing" }}`.  What this will do is if `object_name.object_atribute` is not empty it will render `object_name.object_atribute` and if its empty it will render "nothing". This is [built-in template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/el/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/).

Coming to your problem , Django does not have built in " _ " tag. "_" generally related with [translation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/translation/), probably they wrote a [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ko/2.1/howto/custom-template-tags/) and give name to it as " _ ".